# VS2010 DLLs not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have a solution (ASP.NET, .NET 4.0) that doesn't seem to be updating its dlls properly.  I noticed that, when I compile it after making changes, it doesn't see the additions that I've made.

I recently switched the targeted platform on the solution to x86, because we're now deploying it onto a x64 server and I am now maintaining it on a x64 Win7 machine.  (I don't know if that might have something to do with it, see below.)  After I isolated the problem, when I was testing, I found out that if I chose "view in browser" on one of the aspx files, it suddenly saw the changes that I had made earlier.  I combed through the directories in the main project's bin folder, and I noticed dlls were being saved to two different places: the root of the bin folder, and bin/x86/debug/.  The first location was getting updated when I simply compiled the solution, and the second was getting updated when I used "view in browser" on one of the aspx files.

Does anyone know of an errant setting which might cause this behavior?

Update: The answer provided by @Vinkal leads me to believe that Debug is looking at the `bin/` folder for compiled code rather than `bin/x86/debug/`, where the code is being compiled to.  Is it possible that could be the core problem?

Comment: right click your solution, click `Configuration Manager`, check if your project is selected to be built.

Comment: Do you have any native assemblies? Anything that is not .NET?

Comment: @dotctor, all projects in the solution are checked to be built in the solution's configuration manager.

Comment: @beautifulcoder, I do have two external dlls, but I have had them integrated with the solution for some time before this started happening.

Comment: Is there any post build command set to copy files to different location?

Comment: @ArindamNayak, no.  There are no post-build commands.

Comment: Why dont you use ProcessMonitor to see where VS is compiling the DLL? I'd also recommend that you delete the Obj folder and the suo file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I combed through the directories in the main project's bin folder, and
>   I noticed dlls were being saved to two different places: the root of
>   the bin folder, and bin/x86/debug/. The first location was getting
>   updated when I simply compiled the solution, and the second was
>   getting updated when I used "view in browser" on one of the aspx
>   files.

Check `Configutation Manager` as to what `platform` is selected as shown in the below screen shot#1.

**Screen shot #1: Configuration Manager**

[image: Configuration Manager]

if you create the new `platform` (here `x86`), `Output Path` is automatically set to `bin\x86\Debug\`. See the screenshot below.

**Screen shot #2:** **Build Settings when Project Properties is selected**

[image: Build Event Option from Project Properties]

So when you compile the project, Binaries will be copied according to `Output Path` (here in my case, `bin\x86\Debug\` for the `Platform x86` which is set in `Platform Target`). Confirm as shown in the screen shot below, where all binaries are copied when you compile. As you have mentioned, when you compile the solution, **Root of the bin folder** is getting updated. So your project `Output Path` must be set to **Root of the Bin folder** for the whatever `Platform (Any CPU, x86 or x64)` you have set in `Platform Target`

**Note:** If `Post-Build event commmand` is set to copy Binaries, it will also be  copied to the `Path` specified in `Post-Build event command`.

[image]

**View in Browser:** When page is opened using `View in browser`, page will again be compiled and Binaries are copied according to the `Output Path`specified in `Project Properties` as shown in the **screen shot #2**. As you have mentioned that `bin\x86\Debug\` is updated when you view the page in Browser, it indicates that `Output Path` is set to `bin\x86\Debug\` in your `Project Properties`, In the screen shot shown below, when page is opened using `View in Browser`, Binary is going to `Bin` folder and Platform is selected as `Any CPU`

[image]

**Post-build event command:** if you have also set the `Post-build event command`, as shown in the screen shot below, to copy the path in different location, in both the cases (i.e. when you compile and `View in Browser`), it will be copied to the `Path` specified in `Post-build event command`

[image]

**EDIT:**

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), use the `<probing>` Element:

You can use the  element in the **application configuration file** to specify subdirectories the runtime should search when locating an `assembly`. The following example shows how to specify directories the runtime should search.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The `privatePath` attribute contains the directories that the runtime should search for `assemblies`. If the application is located at C:\Program Files\MyApp, the runtime will look for `assemblies` that do not specify a code base in C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin, C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin2\Subbin, and C:\Program Files\MyApp\Bin3. **The directories specified in privatePath must be subdirectories of the application base directory**

So in your case, modify the `web.config` as shown below

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin\x86\debug"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the exposition and images!  They always help.
I did check my solution, and it all seems to happen as you show.  Building the projects sends them to bin\x86\Debug\, but running 'view in browser' compiles the projects to bin\.  I do *not* have any post-build events set up.
From the behavior and your descriptions, I guess that Debug is looking at bin\ for the compiled code and pdb files.  Do you know why this is, and how to tell it to look at the x86 folders?

Comment: if Debug is looking at bin folder, Can't you change the `Output Path` from bin\x86\Debug\ to \bin so that building the projects send them to \bin folder instead of \bin\x86\debug?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to overcome this issue by changing different configurations in Tools -> Options-> Debugging -> Symbols